# @extends('layout') laravel. Blade Template System seems like Not working

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to use the laravel's template system: `blade` but seems like not working when using the code below in the file `users.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
Users! @stop
```

and browser,

```
 @extends('layout')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should work if you have a template file at /app/views/layout.blade.php that contains

```
<p>Some content here</p>

@yield('content')

<p>Some additional content here</p>
```

Then in your /app/views/user.blade.php, the content

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

<p>This is the user content</p>

@stop
```

If you call `return View::make('user')` you should have the compiled content

```
<p>Some content here</p>

<p>This is the user content</p>

<p>Some additional content here</p>
```

I hope that helps clarify things for you. If not, can you provide your template file locations and the relevant content?

Comment: Yes, you right, he error was the space in white in the top the file layout.blade.php

Comment: I'm new to Laravel and it's a pity that the Blade template breaks so easily only because of a single misplaced whitespace....

Comment: Is there a way to auto extends each file? mean we don't need to write `@extends` each time.

Answer (score 2):

**Just remove the extra space or anything before @extends('yourlayoutfile').**

It should be the first thing to be rendered in the file.

I was facing the same problem and tried many things.Suddenly I found a single space at the starting of the file before @extends.

Removed the space and is working fine.

Thanks.

Format:

```
@extends('layouts.default')
 @section('content') 
.....
 @stop
```

---Edit----

If this didnt work then try :

Copy all the content in the file and then delete the file.

Create a new file and save it as filename.blade.php

Only after saving the file paste the content into the page.
Save the changes and run it.

This works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your layout?

If its in `app/views/layouts`, then it should be

```
@extends('layouts.index')
```

(assuming the name is index.blade.php)

ex: `@extends('layouts.foo')` equals a file in `app/views/layouts/` called either `foo.blade.php` or `foo.php`. (depending if you use blade)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. What is did is:
1. in routes.php

```
Route::get('about', 'AboutController@index');
```

that
AboutController is a controller file AboutController.php in app/controllers
index is a function inside that controller.

2.Create AboutController.php in app/controllers

```
class class AboutController extends BaseController {
    protected $layout = 'layouts.default';
    $this->layout->content = View::make('pages.about');
}
```

You can look at this reference: [Defining A Layout On A Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/templates)

Answer (score 0):

By default,`Laravel` has a `layouts` folder inside `views` folder, i.e. `app/views/layouts` and in this folder you keep your layout files, i.e. `app/views/layouts/index.master.php` and if you have something similar then you should use something like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <p>Page Content</p>
@stop
```

This will inherit/use the `master.blade.php` file (as layout) from `layouts` folder, here, `layouts.master` means `layouts/master.blade.php`.

In your `master.blade.php` file you mast have this

```
@yield('content')
```

So, data/content from the view between `@section('content')` and `@stop` will be dumped in the place of `@yield('content')` of your layout.

You can use any name for your `layout` file, if it's `layouts/main.blade.php` then you should use

```
@extends('layouts.main')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you inserted the css link in App.blade.php

For me **By default there is no link to the css file**

Insert the following link in app.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "/css/app.css" >
```

now its works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

list things to make sure

- file name and path properly given
- double-check .blade.php file extention

layouts.admin.blade.php

```
  <section class="content" style="padding-top: 20px">
                @yield('content')
            </section>
```

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')

<p> this is Order  index view</p>


@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Answer (score -1):

let's say you have 'master.blade.php' and 'index.blade.php'. 
and both of files are in views->home directory. when you want to use @extends in 'index.blade.php' by calling 'master.blad.php' , you should write in index.blade.php file this statment:

```
@extends('home.master')
```

not

```
@extends('master')
```

Comment: Putting your entire answer in a code block is confusing. Please put only code in code blocks.

Comment: @kittycat3141: sorry it was my mistake.

Answer (score -3):

Simply save your source using encoding `UTF-8 without signature`.