# Laravel web page is not loading properly

Tags: css, laravel, layout, laravel-blade

I'm following a laravel tutorial on youtube and everything work fine from the beginning but i get perplexed when some web pages are not loading properly.

I tried these solutions but they did not resolve my issues.

1) [@extends('layout') laravel. Blade Template System seems like Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458885/extendslayout-laravel-blade-template-system-seems-like-not-working)

2) [Laravel @extends('layouts.app') not working on some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283283/laravel-extendslayouts-app-not-working-on-some-pages)

my problem is similar to no.2 above, i tried the solutions given there but they do not work for me.

My css files are located in the right folder, which is public/css/app.css, but it's empty is it supposed to be empty?? if not, then what am i supposed to write in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use bootstrap cdn link from the official website, add it app. blade. Php, and see if it work

Answer (score 0):

use this CDN on your project. I should be definitely working. and try to sure your internet connection

Comment: yes it worked. but i have another problem now. i cannot log out now because the drop down menu for logout is not working. i changed the `style="display: none;" into style="display: inline-block;"` in the app.blade.php but nothing changes.